# What IoT protocol would I use to for devices on the international space station?

Tags: iot, azure-iot-hub

I am creating a few function app samples and one use case is updating software for a device on the international space station. Anyone know what protocol is used?

Answer (score 2):

Azure IoT Hub supports three protocols: AMQP, MQTT, and HTTPs.

Choose AMQP or MQTT except for the device only support HTTPs.

Choose AMQP if that require connecting multiple devices over the same TLS connection.

Choose MQTT if the device has limited resources (for example, less than 1-MB RAM) because it has a smaller footprint than the AMQP libraries.

It depends on your concern.

[Reference - choose a communication protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-protocols)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your devices are connected through IoT Hub. 
You can follow the device management patterns: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-device-management-overview

Specifically: **Firmware Update**. Which should be similar to updating software.

[image: Firmware Update]

*Device Twin* should be used for IoT devices regarding management since devices can't guarantee "always online" connection. In the case of device twin, a state cache is stored in IoT Hub, when the device reconnects it can retrieve the updated state from cloud and update the device accordingly.